# Использовать свойство родительского класса в дочернем

Tags: php, ооп

Учу ООП в PHP и столкнулся с глупой проблемой, но не могу найти ее решение в интернете (возможно проблема слишком очевидна). У меня есть 2 класса, родительский и дочерний. Родительский класс с помощью конструктора получает из формы определенные данные, но эти данные мне также нужны в дочернем классе, но я почему-то не могу их оттуда получить (не знаю как).

Я пытался это сделать разными способами (создавал конструктор, передача функцией, parent), но что-то я делаю неправильно.

Мой IDE подсказывает мне что конструктор в дочереем классе перезаписывает конструктор в родительском. Если контруктор не создавать в дочерем, то все работает. 
Если же присвоть коснтруктору свойсто `private`, то не могу инициализировать объект.

Как мне использовать данные из родительского класса, напрмиер `$email` в дочернем и при этом иметь возможнолсть создавать коснтрукторы в каждом классе?

Вот код

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public $name  = 'name ';
    public $s_name  = 's_name ';
    public $email = 'email ';
    public $ticket = 'ticket ';
    function __construct(){
        $this->name = $_POST['name'];
        $this->s_name = $_POST['s_name'];
        $this->email = $_POST['email'];
        $this->ticket = $_POST['ticket'];
    }
}
$obj = new MyClass();

class NewClass extends MyClass {
    public $test = "test";
    function __construct(){
        $this->test = "test test ";
    }
    function newMethod() {
        echo $this->name;
        echo $this->s_name;
        echo $this->email;
        echo $this->ticket;
    }
}
$objTest = new NewClass();
$objTest->newMethod();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public $name  = 'name ';
    public $s_name  = 's_name ';
    public $email = 'email ';
    public $ticket = 'ticket ';
    function __construct(){
        $this->name = $_POST['name'];
        $this->s_name = $_POST['s_name'];
        $this->email = $_POST['email'];
        $this->ticket = $_POST['ticket'];
   }
}


$obj = new MyClass();


class NewClass extends MyClass {
    public $test = "test";
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->test = "test test ";
    }
    function newMethod() {
        echo $this->name;
        echo $this->s_name;
        echo $this->email;
        echo $this->ticket;
    }
}


$objTest = new NewClass();
$objTest->newMethod();
```

Дело в том что вы действительно в дочернем классе, переопределяете конструктор родительского класса, по этому в конструкторе дочернего вам надо первым делом вызвать родительский, это делается с помощью `parent::__construct();`.

P.S: общие советы по коду, 1) всегда обрамляйте методы и свойства модификаторами доступа. 2) не выводите информацию в методах, лучше просто возвращайте ее, это позволит лучше контролировать код. 3) давайте свойствам и методам `camelCase` имена, то есть каждая новое слово в названии начинаете с большой буквы, пример `my_email` превратится в `myEmail`.

Comment: `первым делом вызвать родительский` зависит от логики. Можно вызвать первым, можно вызвать в середине, можно не вызывать вообще

Comment: Да, конечно, стоит обращать внимание на самом логику конструктора дочернего класса, просто если по возможности вызывать его первым, код становиться более понятным.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно вызвать конструктор родительского класса

```
class NewClass extends MyClass {
    public $test = "test";
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->test = "test test ";
    }
}
```